# how to init animated vector in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, animatedvectordrawable

I followed [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable) and created my first animated vector in android studio.

my vector is:

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
  android:width="491.4dp"
  android:height="297.83dp"
  android:viewportWidth="491.4"
  android:viewportHeight="297.83"
  android:drawable="@drawable/ic_logo">
  <target android:name="name1">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
      <objectAnimator
        android:duration="2000"
        android:repeatCount="-1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse">
        <propertyValuesHolder android:propertyName="alpha" >
          <keyframe
            android:fraction="0"
            android:value="1f" />
          <keyframe
            android:fraction=".5"
            android:value="0f" />
          <keyframe
            android:fraction="1"
            android:value="1f" />
        </propertyValuesHolder>
      </objectAnimator>
    </aapt:attr>
  </target>
  <target android:name="name2">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
      <objectAnimator
        android:duration="2000"
        android:repeatCount="-1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse">
        <propertyValuesHolder android:propertyName="alpha" >
          <keyframe
            android:fraction="0"
            android:value="1f" />
          <keyframe
            android:fraction=".5"
            android:value="0f" />
          <keyframe
            android:fraction="1"
            android:value="1f" />
        </propertyValuesHolder>
      </objectAnimator>
    </aapt:attr>
  </target>
</animated-vector>
```

It seems I need to init it in the activity to set animation to work. But I did not find any tutorial about how to init it in Kotlin. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: FYI, that's not a tutorial. It's the official documentation of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you apply this Drawable. If it's set on an ImageView, you can use

```
(imageView.drawable as? Animatable)?.start()
```

If it's the background of a view you can use

```
(view.background as? Animatable)?.start()
```

Comment: Thank you! It wasted all of my day finding a proper solution for it!!!

Comment: Sure thing. You can also cast it to AnimatedVectorDrawable, but Animatable is more versatile because all the different types of animated drawables implement it so your code won't have to change if you switch to a different type of animated drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is an imageview with this vector drawable on it

```
ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.animatedImage);

AnimatedVectorDrawable drawable = (AnimatedVectorDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();

drawable.start(); //this starts the animation

drawable.setVisible(true,true); //this also starts the animation from start
```